# Right approach to boost the current of a signal to drive a speaker

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, speakers

I have a circuit which can produce three different waveform signals ( Square, Sine and Triangle). The output amplitude of these signals goes from +5V to -5V Peak to peak. However the output from this circuit can only supply a current of 20mA. I have been meaning to drive a 8ohm/1Watt speaker using these signals.

Upon searching I come across few options. Making a current amplifier using Opamp, transistors or use some dedicated chips like TDA7294. Am wondering what would be the best way to approach this without making it a overkill.

Comment: Can you consider reducing the output amplitude of your design? If so, consider a TDA8551. It will run off of a single +5 V supply rail and, because it is bridged, deliver 1 W into an 8 Ohm load. Can you consider the idea of reducing the voltage gain you already have? Or is that a given, here? (You could just attenuate using a resistor divider. But again I don't know if that's something you'd accept.) A fully discrete design would involve "short circuit protection" and possible "*modest* foldback current protection" and other aids to avoid shoot-through. So the discrete design is complex.

Comment: Reducing the output amplitude is not a viable option since the signal generator will be using MAX038 chip. The output voltage is mentioned to swing between +5V and -5V and  there is no provisions in the chip to control the gain as far as I have seen. Thank you for your inputs, I would like the design to be less complex, so I may have exclude the elements that brings complexities.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Image source : [here](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/bipolar_transistor_cookbook_part_7)

Use a complimentary push-pull amplifier since your signal have both negative and positive peaks.

Comment: Of course this design can be improved further with an opamp and an feedback path to ged rid of the distortion in the middle of the signal when one transistor is in the "non linear" region

Comment: Yes, yes, of course, I only provided a bare-bone version.

Comment: Thank you for the design I will give this a try.